# PHP MYSQL insert throwing an error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've tried finding a fix to this, in fact some of this code was ripped out of previous "fixes" I found that didn't work. I'm pretty new to php so I may be missing something obvious. Here's the source.

```
<?php
$device=$_POST['Device'];
$license=$_POST['License'];
$tbl_name="tablename";

$con = mysql_connect("url", "name", "pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$query="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Id, Device Key,License Key)VALUES('', '$device', '$license')";

if (!(mysql_query($query,$con)))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "1 device added was added.";


mysql_close($con)
?>
```

This is my error

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Key,License Key)VALUES('', 'Device Key Here', 'License Key Here')' at line 1"
```

Comment: echo out the $query and see what it is actually.  Should give you some hints

Comment: i usually do:   $query = "insert into ".$tbl_name."() values ()" //if i have to do it your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic SQL syntax: identifiers (field names, table names, etc...) cannot have spaces in them:

```
$query="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Id, Device Key,License Key)VALUES('', '$device', '$license')";
                                        ^---wrong   ^---wrong
```

Generally speaking, you should never have spaces in your names. Use an `_` instead, if you have to.

If you can't/won't rename the fields, you'll have to properly quote them:

```
$query="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Id, `Device Key`,`License Key`)VALUES('', '$device', '$license')";
```

Comment: true.  He should replace \s with _

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm pretty new to SQL as well. Definitely going to leave spaces out when possible. Also when I tried to properly quote them I Was using ' instead of ` which continued to cause errors.

Comment: `'` is used for strings. you can't use strings as field/table identifiers